# Patch - Update SharePoint List in Powerapps

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps

I want to update a SharePoint list that would have the results filtered by a choice column with a certain value. From that selection I then want to update another choice column with a specific value from the choice selection available. I understand because it's a choice column I have to use odata to update this. I am also using the patch function.

The way I am trying to update this is on a browse gallery view. I've inserted a button, with the following formula:

```
Patch(
    'Q-Central Package Tracking',
    First(Filter('Q-Central Package Tracking', Initial_x0020_Destination.Value = "Ecart")),
    {
        Final_x0020_Destination: "EMR",
        '@odata.type': "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference"
    })
```

Is this the right way to go about updating the list? With just a button? Should the button navigate away from the page for it to update the results? Not sure how that would work.

Right now, the above formula does not work. I had a suggestion that I am missing a baserecordstable, but I am not sure what I would be putting in for that....

My data source is 'Q-Central Package Tracking'. 
The first column I am filtering by is 'Initial_x0020_Destination.Value'.
The column I want to update is 'Final_x0020_Destination'.

This is a modern list, on an O365 environment.

[The error hovering over the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1Wxi.jpg)

[Clicking in the formula shows this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h24S7.jpg)

Any insights would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please paste images in the question rather than upload on another site and just link here, When the links become broken for any reason, the question would remain less valuable to the community

Answer (score 1):

The choice column is a "reference" to the list of choices, so it needs to be sent as an object. If you change your expression to:

```
Patch(
    'Q-Central Package Tracking',
    First(Filter('Q-Central Package Tracking', Initial_x0020_Destination.Value = "Ecart")),
    {
        Final_x0020_Destination: {
            Value: "EMR",
            '@odata.type': "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference"
        }
    })
```

It should work.

Comment: Thanks for the assist, it still seems to be missing something though! 

This is passing and navigating to another page, whereas the previous formula I tried, wouldn't navigate away. I took that to mean, it wasn't passing the first part of the formula, and so wasn't going to navigate. However the list isn't updating from that patch. Is there anything else I should be trying?